# Deploying static website on Centos 7 using Apache

Tags: apache, centos

i have trouble on set up home.html the main page.
When i set up virtual host on httpd.conf with options: -indexes , the main page return status 403 and index.html,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias cninfineon.com
ServerAdmin root@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/website
DirectoryIndex home.html 
ErrorLog /var/www/website/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/website/log/access.log combined
Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>

    <Directory "/var/www/website">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
        
    Include conf.d/autoindex.conf



Result:
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2023 09:52:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Oct 2014 13:20:58 GMT
ETag: "1321-5058a1e728280"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4897
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

however, i set up with options: indexes FollowSymLinks, the main page return status 200 and index of file directory.

File Structure:
/var/www/website/
home.html, file contain photo, file with log

How should i to set home.html as the main page or solve 403 status code when i set as disable autoindex?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can set **home.html** on **DirectoryIndex** of **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**.

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php home.html,
</IfModule>
```

And then run:
`sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`